# Instagram user page parsing (with proxy, without API)

Tags: ruby, parsing, proxy, instagram

I need to parse instagram user page without API and with proxy, and I use code like below

```rb
def client(options = {})
  Faraday.new('https://www.instagram.com', ssl: { verify: false }, request: { timeout: 10 }) do |conn|
    conn.request :url_encoded
    conn.proxy options[:proxy]
    conn.adapter :net_http
  end
end

response = client.get('some_username/', proxy: URI('//111.111.111.111:8080'))

response.status # 302
response['location'] # "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/"
```

But previously, just a few days ago, code above worked as expected, i.e. had return 200 status and body with user page. Moreover code `Faraday.get('https://www.instagram.com/some_username/')` without proxy works fine, i.e. returns 200 status and body with user page. I've also tried the same by other clients, and result the same, success without proxy and redirect with it.

Client needs some additional specific configuration for working with proxy, maybe?

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure, but it looks like a problem with proxy, i.e. instagram somehow detects buyed/free proxies, maybe, and redirects requests fromt thats proxies (I've used buyed pack of proxies), because I've tried to use my own proxy and it's works.

Comment: Now would probably be a good time to re-read Instagram's [Terms of Use](https://help.instagram.com/581066165581870).

Comment: i had same problem when try to create Instagram crawler by Selenium, but i resolved this problem by using dedicated proxies. You can use dedicated proxies or rotate proxies for scraping content of Instagram without login, if you have to login to get some contents what you want, i suggest you to use dedicated proxies. I suggest you to use [blazingSEO](https://billing.blazingseollc.com/hosting/aff.php?aff=713) proxies for cheap price and stabilization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instagram made a changes lately. They are most likely have some special AI or use some service which review your IP address, which ISP you use, is it belonging to organization like Digitalocean, OVH, etc or residential, how many requests are you making to which endpoints, how are you making them, how many accounts you use on it, and how quickly you change them etc.

Right now if you hit the limits of **scraping** instagram you will be redirected to `LoginAndSignupPage`(you can find it in source code). Be aware that login on this point won't work - instagram will just return `429 error code`, meaning too many requests. Also after every such block most likely your IP address is even less reliable, so if you will start scraping again after block it will get blocked even faster.

I guess the easiest way will be just use residential ip with enough high delay between requests - like 3-5 seconds, and even better if you can use somehow real accounts, and don't overuse them, as well try to make any other requests in meantime, like getting some posts, opening single post or something.

You can ignore pretty much any free IP proxy list available on google, 99% of those ips on it are banned, almost same with ips from Digitalocean, OVH etc, many of them are blocked as well.

Comment: Got exactly the same problem, went through quite a lengthy investigation and came to very similar conclusions. The thing is: How do companies like https://igblade.com/europeanspaceagency still scrap content? As far as I see API doesn't allow you to download info about profiles other than self.

Comment: Im guessing they are just have many fake accounts with many phone numbers added, some automatization to solve any challenges, use many residential ip from many providers etc. I guess it is possible somehow.

Answer (score 0):

instagram is indeed very hard to bypass and you need to rotate your proxies often to avoid blocking. try https://rapidapi.com/neotank/api/instagram130 to mitigate this - it rotates proxies for you..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).